# segmentation error in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

Please tell me why the segmentation error is there in my program there is no error . 
I also tried to debug it but it never goes inside the for statement.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node* link;
    } *start;

main()
{ 
    int i,n,m;
    start=NULL;

    printf("enter the number of nodes you want");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("enter the element you want to insert");
            scanf("%d",&m);
            create_list(m);
        }
}

create_list(int data)
{ 
    struct node *q,*temp;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=data;
    temp->link=NULL;

    if(start==NULL)
        start=temp;
    else
        {
        while(q->link!=NULL) q=q->link;
        q->link=temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: Its mostly a bad pointer

Comment: in `create_list`, `q` is uninitialised when used.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to at least find out which line crashes?

Comment: can you point it out?@SaeidYazdani

Comment: yes line 13 crashes@immibis

Comment: I doubt line 13 crashes, it's the `scanf` call and there's nothing wrong with that. Also, please learn how to format and indent your code, it's more or less unreadable.

Comment: There are also other problems with your code: You don't declare a function prototype for the `create_list` function, you don't give a return type for the function, your `main` function declaration is wrong (it's specified, actually written in the C specification, to be either `int main(int, char *[])`or `int main(void)`). I also thought you didn't initialize the `start` pointer, it's easy to miss in the wall of unformatted code.

Comment: Start with adding `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` to your compilation command.

Comment: Just try running it with gdb or ddd if you want something graphical.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to initialize `q` before using it:

```
q = start;
while(q->link!=NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You haven't initialized `q` in `create_list()` and used it -

```
while(q->link!=NULL)
```

Intialize `q=start;`  before this loop.

2.Also `free` the allocated memory for `temp` in function.

3.`main()` should be `int main(void)` and what is type of `create_list`? Declare its prototype before `main`.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `create_list` local pointer `q` was not initialized

```
struct node *q,*temp;
            ^^^
```

However it is accessed in the loop

```
while(q->link!=NULL)
```

I think you mean the following

```
else
{
    q = start;
    while ( q->link != NULL ) q = q->link;

    q->link = temp;
}
```

Take into account that the function should be declared before its usage. Place it declaration for example before main. And its return type shall be `void` and specified explicitly. Also function main shall have return type `int`.

For example

```
void create_list( int data );

int main( void )
{
    //...
```

And it is a good idea to free all dynamically allocated memory before exiting the program.

Also header `<malloc.h>` is not a standard C header. You should use `<stdlib.h>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

After all suggestions from the above it will be clearly in the future if you try to show some work of your clear codding and to respect the minimum  standard.

Here is a way of how should be looking your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> /* You need stdlib not malloc */

void create_list(int data); /* If you don't declare your function the compiler doesn't know nothing about create_list */

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
}*start;

int main(void){  /* Here return type of main is int and if no arg needed should be used void */
    int i,n,m;
    start=NULL;
    printf("enter the number of nodes you want");
    if((scanf("%d",&n)) != EOF)  /* always check scanf's return */

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("enter the element you want to insert");
        if((scanf("%d",&m)) != EOF)   /* here the same: always check scanf's return */
        create_list(m);
    }

    return 0; /* return of main should be 0 or one of the following: EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE, but 0 will be ok because it is standard*/
}

void create_list(int data){  /* here should be explicit what kind of function is */
    struct node *q,*temp;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); /* if you allocate memory dynamically ..... */
    temp->data=data;
    temp->link=NULL;

    if(start==NULL){
        start=temp;
    }else{
        q = start;
        while(q->link!=NULL){
            q=q->link;
            q->link=temp;
        }
    }

    free(temp);  /* .....then always free it */
}
```